# Убрать движение карты при OnMarkerClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, marker

При нажатии на маркер, карта по умолчанию помещает его по центру экрана, как сделать что-бы никаких движений не было?

Вот инициализация карты:

```
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.contentView)).getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
        mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mapSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mapSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mapSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    }
```

Вот `onMarkerClick` :

```
  @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if (clickedMarkerId == null) {
        clickedMarkerId = marker.getId();
        changeMarkerIcon(clickedMarkerId, true);
    } else {
        if (!clickedMarkerId.equals(marker.getId())) {
            changeMarkerIcon(clickedMarkerId, false);
            clickedMarkerId = marker.getId();
            changeMarkerIcon(clickedMarkerId, true);
        } else {
            changeMarkerIcon(clickedMarkerId, false);
            clickedMarkerId = null;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Как можно увидеть просто запускается функция по смене иконки, вот сама функция:

```
private void changeMarkerIcon(String markerId, boolean isClicked) {
    mMarkersPool.get(markerId).setIcon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(
                    isClicked ? R.drawable.ic_location_on_map_1_1 : R.drawable.ic_location_on_map_1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена. Вот ответ, пользователям может быть полезный:

Как мы видим `onMarkerClick`возвращает `false`:

```
  @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
...
return false;
}
```

По-этому движение и происходит, стоит поменять на `true`

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать во время клика получить координаты камеры и высоту, а потом просто в конце onClick перенаправить камеру на место. Хотя возможно дерганье т.к. не пробовал на практике. Но как вариант имеет право на жизнь.